# Why $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}) \times\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I don't see why the cartesian product of two sigma-algebras is not always a sigma algebra ($\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}$ is the Borel sigma-algebra).

Comment: Is ${\mathscr B}(\mathbb{R})$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @anomaly Yes, it is. I'm a little confused about that fact, I Don't see why it happens

Comment: @Math1000 I read that before asking but still with The doubt. I'm asking this because my probability professor told us that fact, but he didn't explained that, so I'm curious about the reason why this happens.

Comment: The answers to the linked question give many different explanations for why the cartesian product of two $\sigma$-algebras is not (in general) a $\sigma$-algebra. It's clear that these explanations were not sufficient for you, but it's not clear why you are still confused. To try to pinpoint the issue: at which point in reading @GWu's answer did you become confused?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Sorry, now I understand why is not closed in the union, but I'm having troubles with the complement..

Comment: @diracdeltafunk oh! I think that the intuitive idea of why isn't closed in their complements is because we can construct a rectangle as a complement for the rectangle given by $(-\infty, a]\times(-\infty, b]$ ?

Comment: Notably, as soon as we realize the cartesian product is not closed under union, we're done! $\sigma$-algebras need to be closed under union, so not being closed under union means you cannot be a $\sigma$-algebra.

To answer your question, though, I think you have the right idea, if you meant to say "can't" instead of "can". If the cartesian product were closed under complements, then the complement of every rectangle would need to be a rectangle. But it's easy to find examples of rectangles whose complements are not rectangles -- e.g. $(-\infty,a] \times (-\infty,b]$ or $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Thanks a lot! Yes, I forgot to write the 't haha. Now I understand why the cartesian product is not a sigma-algebra :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that by the Cartesian product you mean the collection of all sets of the form $B_1 \times B_2$ where $B_1, B_2 \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Note that the singleton sets $B_1 = \{(1,1)\} = \{1\} \times \{1\}$ and $B_2= \{(2,2)\} = \{2\} \times \{2\}$ are in this collection.   Prove that their union $B_1 \cup B_2 = \{(1,1), (2,2)\}$ is not, i.e there do not exist any sets $C_1, C_2 \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $C_1 \times C_2 = \{(1,1), (2,2)\}$.   So this collection is not even closed under finite unions.  (It's not closed under complements either, which you might also like to show.)

Comment: I like to short-hand this as "the union of two rectangles isn't necessarily a rectangle".